# Performing UMAP dimension reduction on inconsistently shaped data - python

Tags: python, data-science

first question, I will do my best to be as clear as possible.

If I can provide UMAP with a distance function that also outputs a gradient or some other relevant information, can I apply UMAP to non-traditional looking data? (I.e., a data set with points of inconsistent dimension, data points that are non-uniformly sized matrices, etc.) The closest I have gotten to finding something that looks vaguely close to my question is in the documentation here (https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding_space.html), but this seems to be sort of the opposite process, and as far as I can tell still supposes you are starting with tuple-based data of uniform dimension.

I'm aware that one way around this is just to calculate a full pairwise distance matrix ahead of time and give that to UMAP, but from what I understand of the way UMAP is coded, it only performs a subset of all possible distance calculations, and is thus much faster for the same amount of data than if I were to take the full pre-calculation route.

I am working in python3, but if there is an implementation of UMAP dimension reduction in some other environment that permits this, I would be willing to make a detour in my workflow to obtain this greater flexibility with incoming data types.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithmically this is quite possible, but in practice most implementations do not support anything other than fixed dimension vectors. If computing the all pairs distances is not tractable another option is to try to find a way to featurize or vectorize the data in a way that will allow for easy distance computations. This is, of course, not always possible. The final option is to implement things yourself, but this requires handling the nearest neighbour search, which is likely a non-trivial coding project in and of itself.

Comment: Well, it's good to know that this isn't within the scope of the current implementation and I can stop searching. I'll consider my options — thanks.